# Accessing variable in URL using $stateParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an AngularJS app and am confused about the $stateParams service. I am trying to assign the Google Maps 'center' variable as the lat and lon values in the URL.

Here is my .config:

```
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider.state('location', {
          url: '/:lat/:lon',
          templateUrl: 'index.html',
          controller: 'MapsCtrl',
          resolve: {
              resolveMap: function (MapService, $stateParams) {
                  return MapService.getData($stateParams.lat, $stateParams.lon, $stateParams.radius);
              }
          }
      });

  })
```

And here is the start of my controller, up to where I define center:

```
.controller('MapsCtrl', ['$scope', "uiGmapLogger", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", "$interval", "$state", "$stateParams",
  function ($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi, $interval, $state, $stateParams, $http) {
      $log.currentLevel = $log.LEVELS.debug;
      var center = { latitude: $stateParams.lat, longitude: $stateParams.lon };
```

I am getting the error: 'angular-google-maps: could not find a valid center property'.

Here is a JS Fiddle, but it does not display any output (likely because of the error above): https://jsfiddle.net/8mtge09w/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're trying to bind the variables before they're set. You need to make sure all the google-map directive params are valid first. You can wrap your `ui-gmap-google-map` directive elements with `ng-if` to be sure your map properties are ready.

I believe you can use

```
ng-if="map.center !== undefined"
```

to be sure. Basically, don't render your elements until valid properties have been bound. You can also set default values and avoid the ng-if.

See [this github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/185) for more details.

Comment: Arch thanks that fixed it! but now I am getting the warning Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys and nothing is loading on the page: http://alainwebdesign.ca/newPL/ . But this wasn't a problem before, and the admin of the repo I got this code from said you won't need API keys... any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Sounds like either they were wrong, or things have changed and you do need a Maps API. No need to worry though, you can get one for free.

Comment: Yeah I have done it before but I'm not sure where to put the key for this app. Would it just be in index.html before the closing body tag?

Comment: IIRC the API key is loaded in the Google API script. Check [this link](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1296) It's passed in a config object

Comment: I went into issue-1169-windows-update.js and under .config, added key: [myKey] but i am still getting the no api key error

Answer (score 0):

Yo should pass latitude and longitude when you change the view.

```
$tate.go(stateName, {}, {latitude: value, longitude: value})
```

In additions to this, when you define a state, you should set the params with the default values.

```
.state(
     .....
     params: {
          latitude: defaultValue,
          longitude: defaultValue
     }
 )
```